# C# Is it possible to use an instance of a base class for different instances of subclasses?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, polymorphism

Here some sample code to explain what i want to do:

First of all i have a base class:

```
    public class BaseClass {
      int k = 100;
    }
```

here are two subclasses:

```
public class SubClassA : BaseClass {}
public class SubClassB : BaseClass {}
```

when i create an instance of SubClassA and change the value of k, i want access the changed value within an instance of SubClassB. here is what i mean:

```
public class TestClass {
 public void doSomething() {
  SubClassA a = new SubClassA();
  SubClassB b = new SubClassB();

  a.k = 500;

  int j = b.k;
 }
}
```

normally j has the value 100, but i want that it have the changed value 500. how can i realize this or is there any design pattern?

Probably it is easy but i dont find a solution. I need several subclasses and one baseclass that is singleton or something like this...

Comment: A real-life use case will help in getting better answers

Comment: I would use association instead of inheritance to handle this.

Answer (score 4):

You would have to make `k` a static variable for it to retain the same value across all instances.

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public static int k = 100;
}
```

Comment: Note that you then *can't* write `a.k = 500;`.

Comment: @Jon: True, but, that wouldn't have worked in the OP's code, either ;)

Comment: @Reed: Unless TestClass is nested inside BaseClass, of course :)

Comment: @Jon: True - though the code shows the end of base class, and it's not flagged partial - would it be possible to have it nested with the BaseClass definition above some other way I'm not seeing?

Comment: @Reed: Not that I can think of. Do you think we're maybe overanalyzing? ;)

Comment: @Jon: Probably - but heh, that's always fun

Comment: @jon: True, it would have to be access as [ClassName].k instead.

Answer (score 3):

You would do that by making the base class field/property static:

```
public class BaseClass {
   protected static int k = 100;
}
```

This would cause the field to be associated with the BaseClass type, not a specific instance - as such, it would be "shared" amongst all subclass instances.

Answer (score 1):

You have two distinct objects here, referred to by the variables `a` and `b`. The fact that they're both subclasses of the same base class is irrelevant. For a change to one to affect the other, they either have to know about each other or both know about some other common object. For example, you *could* have:

```
public class Int32Holder
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

class Foo
{
    private readonly Int32Holder valueHolder;

    public int Value
    {
        get { return valueHolder.Value; }
        set { valueHolder.Value = value; }
    }

    public Foo(Int32Holder valueHolder)
    {
        this.valueHolder = valueHolder;
    }
}
```

Then:

```
Int32Holder holder = new Int32Holder();
Foo a = new Foo(holder);
Foo b = new Foo(holder);
a.Value = 10;
Console.WriteLine(b.Value); // Prints 10
```

However, I would *not* advise this... it makes for pretty confusing behaviour.

There are almost certainly better design patterns for what you're trying to accomplish - but we can't help you with them unless you tell us the bigger picture.

I would recommend *against* using the static variables shown by other answers, unless you really, really want the variable to be associated with the type rather than with any instance of the type.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Can you explain a real-world scenario?

In your example, a and b are difference instances.  They each have a independent k within them, and each can change it, but just because they subclass the same things, they are not "linked" together.

If the baseclass has a static member, it could be changed, but it would be changed globally, not just for this a and b but any other instances of subclass a, b or the base class.

Comment: i thought about this while implementing the mvvm pattern. i have many ViewModels, for each UserControl one and what to do if i have properties to be changed across many usercontrols?